# how to provide custom css for ngbDatepicker in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular

my html code is as follows:

```
<div>

     <div style="color:white">Date Range:</div>
     <div class="input-daterange input-group">
          <input class="form-control" value="2017-01-01"
                 name="dp1" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker 
                 #dp1="ngbDatepicker"
                 (click)="dp1.toggle()"  [ngClass]="'my_group'"
                 (ngModelChange)="changeValue()">
          <span class="input-group-addon">TO</span>
          <input class="form-control" value="2017-01-01"
                 name="dp2" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker 
                 #dp2="ngbDatepicker"
                 (click)="dp2.toggle()" [ngClass]="'my_group'"
                 (ngModelChange)="changeValue()">
      </div>
</div>
```

I want tot change ngbDatepicker remove left poisition to zero. So, i tried to put css as follows:

```
  .my_group {

        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;

}
```

It still didn't worked, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is working

```
.use_your_Main_class /deep/ .ngb-dp-header  { 
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e2e2e2 !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) !important;
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
    background:transparent !important;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me :

```
:host /deep/ ngb-datepicker {
    left: 0px !important;
    right: 0px !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this example:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ngb-dp-months {
  background:green;
}
:host ::ng-deep .ngb-dp-month {
  background:blue;
}

:host ::ng-deep .the-ngb-dp-class {
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not targeting a class - try `.my_group` (notice the period before the name `my_group`)

Like this:

```
.my_group {
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Are you sure it's absolute or fixed (assuming it's parent is relative)?

```
.my_group {
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: even after that it still doesn't fix issue

Comment: You need to make a code snippet or fiddle then, there must be something else going on. Is it absolute or fixed? See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the style classes of datepicker in the node_modules. And check which class you want to override, then use `:host /deep/` for that. As an example, this is how I override the header css for datepicker:

```
:host /deep/ .ngb-dp-header  {
  //...
}
```